# Does Facebook create ID Token for user like Google?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I use Google api to the login of user in mysite, google gives me [ID Token](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth) of the user to validate the user and a refresh token to get the new access token for the user. Now I want to use [Facebook login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web) also so my question is that

Is Facebook also create a Id token for the user when they logging in ?

Is there any refresh token to get new access token or I have to take again permission from the user to get new access token?

How can I authenticate the user who logged in on mysite in backend server of my site?

Comment: If you use the JS SDK, it will automatically give you a fresh short-lived token every time a user that has already logged in to your app before visits your site (if they are logged into Facebook at the same time.) And https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security should answer a lot of the other questions.

Comment: Yes. It helps a lot thanks! but I didn't get the answer of my all questions.